# ChartJS - would like to create a mixed chart with horizontal Bar and a dot to represent the answer from the current user

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to create a mixed chart with horizontal bar chart and a dot to represent the answer from the current user. I have the horizontal bar chart created (please see attached screenshot) and I would like to show a green dot to represent what the current user answered. I am able to show the green dot using a mixed vertical bar chart with a line chart (keeping all points on the line null, except the one that needs to show the green dot), but I am not able to make this work using a horizontal char.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4xrwabq49ufzth/Untitled.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Next time when you ask a question please post the code you already have so people can help you more easily, made a quick example for you you can see underneath here.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'values',
      backgroundColor: "red",
      borderColor: "red",
      data: [120, 23, 24, 45, 51]
    }, {
      type: 'line',
      label: 'point',
      backgroundColor: "green",
      borderColor: "green",
      data: [{
        y: 'Feb',
        x: 27
      }]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    indexAxis: 'y',
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 10,
        hoverRadius: 10
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="myChartDiv">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-beta.11/chart.js" integrity="sha512-1J1wxKm2JepFETRYyEEDHQAjc5ZgRvdYKWdfiP27m1pfDmLQ47joNkTPHVvmfkg7BLktY+Jd0TU1VAuIO81uQg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Amazing! This works great! Thank you so much.

One additional question.. is it possible to highlight one of the labels on the Axes, for example in this case to highlight the "Feb" label with a yellow background or something similar?

Comment: Not by default, you will have to implement that with a custom plugin

Comment: [palluji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15254873/palluji), please mark this answer as accepted if you think it was the solution to your original question (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2358409)